# Recommendations for eCommerce Framework / Products for working with Django?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

We are building out an app in Django and trying to nail down what the right ecommerce framework will be to work with in Django. We've heard of Satchmo. Any other suggestions on ways to approach ecommerce in Django that's clean, simple, cheap and easy to implement? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look on the [LFS](http://www.getlfs.com/) - it is much simpler then Satchmo is

Answer (score 2):

I did a comparison of the options [here](http://readncode.com/blog/the-state-of-ecommerce-in-django/).